# Fogbugz and ELMAH - Communication Plugin

Tags: elmah, fogbugz, error-reporting

My employer is currently trying out Fogbugz and one feature that would be nice is some sort of automation between our exception logger (ELMAH) and case generation in FogBugz. Specifically, it would be great if there were a module to send error reports to FogBugz and then in FogBugz process the error, look for duplicates (perhaps grouped by page name, exception, and offending line), and, if necessary, create a new case.

As far as I can tell this could be achieved by sending an e-mail with ELMAH and then having some sort of plugin on the FogBugz end that parses the report and performs the necessary actions. Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to automatically create new cases in FogBugz you do not have to necessarily write a plug-in. FogBugz has some API for managing cases from other applications:

- There is [BugzScout](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/customers/BugzScout.html) which does a similar thing you ask.
- You can use the [FogBugz XML API](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/API.html) for creating / querying cases and set up your "external work flow".

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make an ELMAH plugin with their new APIs and plugin system, or you can go the easy route and send all exceptions to an email box that FB picks up and creates cases for.

Check out https://developers.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W1 for info on how to make plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I found this FogBugz Elmah integration. Not tested:

http://www.billforney.com/category/C.aspx